# How to deserialize xml to List<T>

Tags: c#, xml

I have object of some type, let's say `Foo`, looking like:

```
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public string Id {get; set;}

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Also i have xml:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>name_1</name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>name_2</name>
    </foo>
</root>
```

What am i doing wrong trying to deserialize that xml to List using `XmlDeserializer` with following code?

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>));
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    list = (List<Foo>)serializer.Deserialize(reader); //error here
}
```

Getting exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException

<root xmlns=''> unexprected .
```

Comment: "some reflection error" - could you be more specific? In general though, you should only use XmlSerializer to deserialize XML which was also *generated* with XmlSerializer. (Or at least, that's significantly more likely to work...)

Comment: well, removed type specification from XmlElement attribute and error is gone now. XML is generated in sql database

Comment: I made a quick test serializing an instance of your class; the typeof(int) produces a reflection error. It works with typeof(string).

Comment: @KaiHartmann Edited question, reflection error gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root element does not match. There are ways to pass it into the constructor of XmlSerializer, but IMO your best bet is to create a wrapper class:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class FooWrapper {
    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public List<Foo> Items {get;set;}
}
```

And pass this type to XmlSerializer.

Comment: Well, this solution is working, but is there a way to get list w/o wrapper?

Comment: try this: `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<foo>), new XmlRootAttribute("root"));`

Comment: @Ric personally I always advocate the wrapper object approach. If the other strategy works too, great.

Comment: @Ric it returns empty collection

Comment: @MarcGravell what if add `XmlRoot("root")` to `Foo` class without wrapper?

Comment: @Sergio the issue is case sensitivity from the xml and the class name `Foo`.

Comment: @Grundy doesn't make sence

Comment: @Ric i see. Thanks for solution, seems that best practice is still wrapper, sadly...

Comment: @Grundy it will be ignored because Foo is not the type of the root object